# How to update value of a text box as if we have typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I creating a firefox add-on which can fill few fields in a from with given input. For example 2nd field of form# 2 on page is a textbox in general following would work.

```
document.forms[2][1].value = "XYZ"
```

I can see this value XYZ in the textbox. But if I go ahead and submit the form, either through script or manually, it throws and error at this textbox. In few cases using the click() after giving the value works.

```
document.forms[2][1].value = "XYZ"
document.forms[2][1].click()
```

But even this fails on few websites. I wont work until we manually place my cursor in the textbox and type.

1. why do the textboxes behave as above?
2. Is there any way of making this work (either in javascript or jQuery)?

Updated:

```
function createValueAttribute(formField, attValue){
formField.focus();
formField.setAttribute("value",attValue);
var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
event.initKeyEvent("keypress",       // typeArg,                                                           
               true,             // canBubbleArg,                                                        
               true,             // cancelableArg,                                                       
               null,             // viewArg,  Specifies UIEvent.view. This value may be null.     
               false,            // ctrlKeyArg,                                                               
               false,            // altKeyArg,                                                        
               false,            // shiftKeyArg,                                                      
               false,            // metaKeyArg,                                                       
                8,               // keyCodeArg,   8 for Backspace                                                   
                0);              // charCodeArg);
formField.dispatchEvent(event);

}
```

Comment: You can try sending key events to the form, however if you do that I think you need to ensure the form field is focused. Here is how: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent

Comment: Other than that though, the method you took is the right one. It may be that these other form fields don't have a value attribute, maybe they are content-editable divs?

Comment: I tried the link you provided and created a function [ createValueAttribute() ] to add the value and then generate a keypress event as updates in the question. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: My friend suggests that it may be because of react-id attribute in input tag, as shown here ( <input class="text-input" name="password" tabindex="0" data-reactid="xyz" type="password"> )